# Openlayers 3 - wfs-t: change name of geometry field

Tags: gis, openlayers-3, geoserver

I am attempting wfs-t on openlayers 3 with the following code:

```
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
  featureNS: 'http://argeomatica.com',
  featureType: 'playa_sample',
  srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
  });
var transactWFS = function(p,f) {
  switch(p) {
  case 'insert':
    node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f],null,null,formatGML);
    break;
  case 'update':
    node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,[f],null,formatGML);
    break;
  case 'delete':
    node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,null,[f],formatGML);
    break;
    }
  s = new XMLSerializer();
  str = s.serializeToString(node);
  $.ajax('https://gsx.geolytix.net/geoserver/geolytix_wfs',{
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'xml',
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'text/xml',
    data: str
    }).done();
  }
```

However, when I run an update transaction (ajax call), it sends the geometry column as "geometry".  I need to change it to be upper case "GEOM":

...

```
<Property>
<Name>geometry</Name>
```

...

**should be:**
...

```
<Property>
<Name>GEOM</Name>
```

...

I tried setting the feature with a hidden property I found (geometryName_):

f.geometryName_ = "GEOM";

But that does not work.  Any help changing the feature to pass "GEOM" to the ajax call would be appreciated.  Thanks

**Update # 1**

As suggested by Bart, I added setGeometryName:

```
case 'update':
    f.setGeometryName("GEOM");
    node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null,[f],null,formatGML);
    break;
```

But that causes openlayers 3 js to error out at:

```
ol.interaction.Modify.prototype.addFeature_
..
if (geometry.getType() in this.SEGMENT_WRITERS) <-- errors out here
```

Error: unable to get property getType object is null

Comment: You need to use setGeometryName on the feature. This will be picked up by the format.

Comment: Bart, tried your suggestion but did not work. See update #1 above.

Comment: You need to make sure that in the values of your feature the geometry is under that key. What does feature.getGeometry() yield after you set the name?

Comment: Bart, openlayers 3.12.0 does not allow using setGeometryName. After I set it, openlayers crashes with above error.  If I do not call setGeometryName, getGeometry does return the geometry of the feature.

Comment: How are your features created and why do they not have the correct geometry name from the start?

Comment: The geometry name is from the back-end table.  It is "GEOM" and was created long before openlayers 3 was around.

Comment: Bart, problem solved.  See solution below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you draw a feature with ol.transaction.Draw if that is the case you need to set your geometry name in the draw interaction object `geometryName:'the_geom'` befor you call 'drawend' event

```
var interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  type: 'MultiPolygon',
  source: Source,
  geometryName:'the_geom'
});
```

if you set the geometryName after drawing is finished (**WRONG** using `feature.setGeometryName()`)openlayers will send a null object to the server.

Comment: This answer works perfectly and should be accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved!

Created a work-around to solve the problem.  If someone has a better solution, please post your answer.

Step 1 - Modify the switch/case statement as follows:

```
...

case 'insert':

// Insert Parameter for new GEOMETRY NODE
f.set('GEOM', f.getGeometry());

node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f], null, null, formatGML);

// Remove default lower case geometry node
removeLowerCaseGeometryNodeForInsert(node);

break;

case 'update':

// Update Parameter for new GEOMETRY NODE
f.set('GEOM', f.getGeometry());

node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [f], null, formatGML);

// Remove lower case geometry node which will cause update to fail
removeNodeForWfsUpdate(node, "geometry");

break;

...
```

Step 2 - Add the following functions to your code:

```
function removeLowerCaseGeometryNodeForInsert(node)
{

  var geometryNodes = node.getElementsByTagName("geometry"), element;
  while (geometryNode = geometryNodes[0])
  {
    geometryNode.parentNode.removeChild(geometryNode);
  }

}

function removeNodeForWfsUpdate(node, valueToRemove)
{
  var propNodes = node.getElementsByTagName("Property");
  for (var i = 0; i < propNodes.length; i++)
  {
    var propNode = propNodes[i];
    var propNameNode = propNode.firstElementChild;
    var propNameNodeValue = propNameNode.firstChild;
    if (propNameNodeValue.nodeValue === valueToRemove)
    {
      propNode.parentNode.removeChild(propNode);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```